# BSTR string manipulation within a loop

Tags: c#, c++, string, interop

I need to manipulate the `StrVal` as the `struct` is marshalled to managed C#. I am trying to use `BSTR` string type, as it saves the memory allocation actions but I am not familiar with unmanaged data types. The problem is that I do not see any changes made to the value.

```
typedef struct {
    int Id;
    BSTR StrVal;
}packet;

packet pks [5];

// ...

 pks[i].StrVal = L"abcdefghij";

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
    pks[i]=i;

    //pks[i].StrVal = SysAllocString(L"abcdefghi"+i);
    pks[i].StrVal[9]=i+'0';
 }
```

How can I accomplish the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the init to

```
pks[i].StrVal = SysAllocString(L"abcdefghij");
```

Comment: didn't pay attention to the last one (; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pks[i].StrVal = L"abcdefghij"` just points the BSTR to a string literal, it doesn't copy the value in the `BSTR`, in addition to the fact that the `BSTR` whilst typedefed to `whar_t*` does not behave like a C string. To work with the [`BSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx) you must limit yourself to the `Sys...` family of functions (e.g. [`SysAllocString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458(v=vs.85).aspx)) or if the ATL is available, use that. To initialise and allocate the string;

```
pks[i].StrVal = SysAllocString(L"abcdefghij");
```

Looking at the `for` loop alone (i.e. not allocating as above), the concatenation could be easily done with [`ATL::CComBSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx);

```
CComBSTR temp(L"abcdefghi");
temp += std::to_wstring(i).c_str();
pks[i].StrVal = temp.Detach();
```

[`VarBstrCat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221621(v=vs.85).aspx) provides another alternate for the concatenation.

Comment: thanks for your good sample code, i have no knowlage of all types you mentioned, and while reviewing the alternative, it's nice that `CComBSTR` let use without allocating. though which approach is less expensive, as i might marshall to managed code, by the M's of them